# java thread safety error in synchronized method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have this class

```
package net.omnosis.mazegame.components;

import net.omnosis.mazegame.SlicedBitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class PlayerLayer extends DrawableLayer {

    private Player player;
    private XY tileImageSize;

    private int[] move = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6 };
    //private int[] move = new int[] { 8 };

    private int moveCount;
    private int moveCountMax = move.length;

    private Bitmap playerBitmap;
    public SlicedBitmap playerTiles;

    private int line;

    private static final int VERTICAL = 0;
    private static final int HORIZONTAL = 8;

    public PlayerLayer(Player player, Bitmap playerBitmap, XY tileImageSize) {

        this.playerBitmap = playerBitmap;
        this.tileImageSize = tileImageSize;
        playerTiles = new SlicedBitmap(playerBitmap, tileImageSize.x(), tileImageSize.y());

        setPlayer(player);

        update();
    }

    public final void setPlayer(Player player) {
        if (this.player != null) {
            this.player.removeListener(this);
        }

        this.player = player;
        player.addListener(this);
        update();
    }

    public void updateDirection() {
        Direction dir = player.getHeading();

        if (dir == Direction.LEFT || dir == Direction.RIGHT) {
            line = HORIZONTAL;
        } else if (dir == Direction.TOP || dir == Direction.BOTTOM) {
            line = VERTICAL;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void animate() {

        if (player.isMoving()) {

            moveCount++;

            if (moveCount >= moveCountMax) {

                player.finishMove();
                moveCount = 0;
            }
        } else {

        }

        updateDirection();
        super.update();
    }

    public void update() {
        updateDirection();
        super.update();
    }

    public XY getSpritePos() {
        XY playerPos = new XY(player.getCurrentPosition().x() * tileImageSize.x() + (tileImageSize.x() / 2), player.getCurrentPosition().y() * tileImageSize.y() + (tileImageSize.y() / 2));
        XY animationPos = getAnimationPos();
        return playerPos.add(animationPos);
    }

    public XY getAnimationPos() {
        double step = (double) tileImageSize.x() / moveCountMax * moveCount;
        return player.getHeading().multiply((int) step);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {

        if (moveCount >= moveCountMax) {
            System.out.println("BUG! MORE: " + moveCount + "  max: " + moveCountMax);
            moveCount = 0;
        }
        return playerTiles.getTile(move[moveCount] + line);
    }
}
```

A thread calls the `animate` method every 10msec. Sometimes I get this output: `BUG! MORE: 12  max: 12` This is because I check the value AGAIN in the `getBitmap()` method. Why?

I dont understand that if the animate is `synchronized`, how can the moveCount be more than 11?

*This happens more frequently if the emulator laggs.*

Comment: `player.finishMove()` isn't calling `getBitmap()` is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing and resetting `moveCount` in a `synchronized` block, but you are not synchronizing on the same lock when you access the `moveCount` variable in the `getBitmap()` method.

This means that Thread A could be in the middle of the `animate()` method, and has incremented `moveCount` to be equal to `moveCountMax`. Thread B then enters `getBitmap()` and reads the value of `moveCount` *before* Thread A resets `moveCount` to 0.

In general, you need to synchronize not just when you write to the value of the variable, but also when you read from it (on the same lock), especially if one of the operations on that variable (like your `animate()` method) involves compound operations (increment, then maybe reset to 0)

BTW, if `moveCountMax` is a constant value (`= moves.length`), mark it as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize all access to shared mutable data.  You synchronize on the increment, which is good, but you do not synchronize on the read in `getBitmap`.  This means a thread can read `moveCount` in `getBitmap` while being incremented or immediately after.

Imagine the case where you increment `moveCount` and before that incrementing thread sets it to 0 another thread calls getBitmap in which `if (moveCount >= moveCountMax) {` can be true at that moment.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt thought I need to synchronize both method.

Comment: @omnosis No problem.  you don't necessarily need to sync the entire method, rather just where you read and write to `moveCount`